# Parsing C# Dictionary with JSON

Tags: c#, javascript, json, dictionary

I am trying to retrieve a Dictionary of key/value pairs from my C# application with JSON, but I am screwing up somewhere. This is my first time with JSON so I am probably just doing something stupid.

C# Code:

```
        else if (string.Equals(request, "getchat"))
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");

            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add(timestamp, "random message");
            data.Add(timestamp, "2nd chat msg");
            data.Add(timestamp, "console line!");

            return Response.AsJson(data);
        }
```

Javascript:

```
function getChatData()
{
    $.getJSON(dataSource + "?req=getchat", "", function (data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(key, val)
        {
            addChatEntry(key, val);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems that you're adding the same key, with different values in your C# Dictionary. Change the key names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dictionary is not serialized as array. Also keys in a dictionary must be unique and you will probably get an exception that a key with the same name has already be inserted when you try to run your server side code. Try using an array of values:

```
var data = new[]
{
    new { key = timestamp, value = "random message" },
    new { key = timestamp, value = "2nd chat msg" },
    new { key = timestamp, value = "console line!" },
};
return Response.AsJson(data);
```

The serialized json should look something like this:

```
[ 
    { "key":"2011.09.03 15:11:10", "value":"random message" }, 
    { "key":"2011.09.03 15:11:10", "value":"2nd chat msg" }, 
    { "key":"2011.09.03 15:11:10", "value":"console line!" }
]
```

now in your javascript you can loop:

```
$.getJSON(dataSource, { req: 'getchat' }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        // use item.key and item.value to access the respective properties
        addChatEntry(item.key, item.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, but I checked out the Framework I am using and it looks like Response.AsJson takes a Model (object) as a parameter. What would be the best alternative to use that works with JSON?

Comment: @Brett Powell, what didn't work? How does the rendered JSON look like? When you inspected the AJAX request in FireBug what did you see?

Comment: Oh my god, I forgot about Firebug (rarely ever do web coding). Was just missing a ')' that resolved it immediately. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Brett Powell, indeed. My mistake sorry. I have fixed my answer.

Comment: Nope, I did the exact same thing in my code, so not a problem at all! One question for you though. I am basically using this as a way to retrieve all the lines out of my C# console application's window, and print them in a web interface. What would be the best method to store timestamp/username/message that can be serialized to JSON?

Comment: @@Brett Powell, in terms of data structure or in terms of storage location? I don't quite understand what do you want to store.

Comment: I need to store the lines from my applications console window. My application launches and manages a java application, so I can get all of the data from the output redirect, but I am not sure of the best storage method for it. Just to simplify, it will basically be 2 strings (user and the message) and the timestamp. As application consoles can get quite long, I am not sure if a Dictionary is the most optimal solution.